# How to fix errors in my Fortran code

Tags: fortran

I am not familiar with errors in Fortran. Could you please explain what are these errors?

```
int.f90(18): error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'K' when expecting one of: ( % : . = =>
do k=0.0 to m
---^

int.f90(19): error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'Q' when expecting one of: ( % : . = =>
 do q=1 to m-1
----^

int.f90(20): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ) ,
 f1=1/(2*pi)*(sqrt((k**2)+(Q**2)-(2*k*cos(t)))
----------------------------------------------^

int.f90(24): error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'I' when expecting one of: ( % : . = =>
 do i=1 to m-1
----^

int.f90(4): error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [INT]
function int(f,a,b,int,m)
-------------------^

int.f90(9): error #6418: This name has already been assigned a data type.   [M]
integer:: i,m
------------^

int.f90(10): error #6557: An =initialization-expr is missing; an initialization expression is required when using the PARAMETER attribute.   [PI]
real,parameter:: pi,pi=3.14
-----------------^

int.f90(10): error #6418: This name has already been assigned a data type.   [PI]
real,parameter:: pi,pi=3.14
--------------------^

int.f90(11): error #6557: An =initialization-expr is missing; an initialization expression is required when using the PARAMETER attribute.   [EPS]
real,parameter:: eps,eps=1.89
-----------------^

int.f90(11): error #6418: This name has already been assigned a data type.   [EPS]
real,parameter:: eps,eps=1.89
---------------------^

int.f90(12): error #6557: An =initialization-expr is missing; an initialization expression is required when using the PARAMETER attribute.   [E]
real,parameter:: e,e=1.602*((10)**(-19))
-----------------^

int.f90(12): error #6418: This name has already been assigned a data type.   [E]
real,parameter:: e,e=1.602*((10)**(-19))
-------------------^

int.f90(21): error #6099: An ENDDO statement occurred without a corresponding DO or DO WHILE statement.
 end do
-^

int.f90(23): error #6099: An ENDDO statement occurred without a corresponding DO or DO WHILE statement.
 end do
-^

int.f90(26): error #6410: This name has not been declared as an array or a function.   [F2]
 s=2*f2(t)+4*f2(t+h)
-----^

int.f90(27): error #6099: An ENDDO statement occurred without a corresponding DO or DO WHILE statement.
 end do 
-^
```

and this is my code:

```
function int(f,a,b,int,m)
implicite none
double precision f1,f2,a,b,m,int,s 
double precision h,t
integer:: k,q
integer:: i,m
real,parameter:: pi,pi=3.14
real,parameter:: eps,eps=1.89
real,parameter:: e,e=1.602*((10)**(-19))
a=0.0
b=pi
m=150
s=0.0
h=(b-a)/m
do k=0.0 to m
do q=1 to m-1
f1=1/(2*pi)*(sqrt((k**2)+(Q**2)-(2*k*cos(t)))
end do
f2=((2*pi*(e**2))/eps)*f
end do
do i=1 to m-1
t=a+(i*h)
s=2*f2(t)+4*f2(t+h)
end do 
int=(h/3)*(s+f2(a)+f2(b)+4*f2(a+h))
print*,int
return
end function int
```

Comment: In general you get better help if you post code in addition to just an error.  Sometimes the real error is on a line prior to the one that the compiler picks.  In this case, I see this "to" in your do loop that seems suspect.  I'm not familiar with that syntax.  The first should be `do k=0,m` unless you're using some newer syntax that I haven't seen. (Also, `k` is probably integer, so assigning `0.0` is either confusing or wrong.)

Comment: Please post the source code. If it is too big, write a new, shorter program which reproduces your error. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I would help but it would not seem right to just give you the solution when you do not even know how to declare the most basic statement like a `do` loop. I suggest you read some tutorials online first.

Comment: You're obviously struggling with the basics of Fortran.  You should first read an introductory tutorial -- http://www.uv.es/dogarcar/man/IntrFortran90.pdf is probably suitable for your level of understanding -- and learn for yourself where some of your mistakes come from and how to fix them.  You may have sensed that the Fortranners here, myself included, are reluctant to answer your question.  That's because it threatens to suck us into teaching you one-to-one and line-by-line.  That's not what SO is for, and not of much interest to most of us.

Answer (score 4):

Your errors are:

1. Your *loop-control* in every one of your do loops is malformed. (Fortran 2008 Cl. 8.1.6.2 R818)

   DO loops are specified as (neglecting optional syntax):

   ```
   do variable=start, end
   ```

   Note the comma rather than the word `to`.
2. Parenthesis must be balanced. (See Fortran 2008 7.1.2.2 R701 *( expr )*)

   Every left parenthesis `(` must have a corresponding right parenthesis `)`.  Your statements assigning `f1` and `f2` both have more left parenthesis than right parenthesis.
3. Declaring a variable twice in the same scoping unit is wrong. (Fortran 2008 Cl. 16.3.1 paragraph 3, see also: Cl. 5.2)

   - To delcare a variable and initialize it, you need only use its name once

     ```
     real, parameter :: pi=3.14
     ```
   - You call the function `int` and a dummy variable `int`.  You need to use different names for these.
   - You declare `m` as both `integer` and `double precision`.  You can only declare it as one type, not two.

Of note:

1. Fix errors starting with the first ones, as later ones can be caused by the compiler throwing out earlier bad statements and will go away when those are fixed.
2. Real values in do loop variables are deleted in the latest standard, and should be avoided in new code. (Fortran 2008 Annex B.1 2(1)).

Your code demonstrates a lack of understanding in Fortran and you will benefit greatly from finding a Fortran tutorial that covers the basics of variables and loops.